# error al ejecutar código en pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
#importar
from numpy import np
import pygame, sys

#iniciar pygame
pygame.init()

#tamaño pantalla
size = width, height = 800, 500

#pantalla
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

while True:
    pass
```

Al ejecutar dice:

> from numpy import np   File
> "c:\Users\x\Desktop\Archivos\x\PyScripts\numpy.py", line 1, in
>
> np.array(( NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: Necesitas importarlo de la siguiente manera. `import numpy as np`

Answer (score 0):

El error está en la línea `from numpy import np` porque el significado de esta línea es **desde el módulo numpy importar un objeto np que puede ser una clase, función o variable** pero no existe ningún objeto interno llamado `np` dentro de `numpy` y por eso arroja error.

Puede ser que lo que quieres es importar `numpy` pero con el nombre más corto `np` entonces puedes usar sustituir la linea mala con `import numpy as np` y el codigo queda asi:

```
import numpy as np
import pygame, sys

#iniciar pygame
pygame.init()

#tamaño pantalla
size = width, height = 800, 500

#pantalla
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

while True:
    pass
```

Comment: Estaría bueno que profundizaras un poco más en lo que hace `import [modulo] as [alias]`, pero igual buena respuesta c:

Answer (score 0):

Profundizando en la respuesta que dió el usuario de arriba!

Cuando introduces lo siguiente: `import numpy as np` lo que estás haciendo es asignarle al modulo numpy un alias, en este caso `np`. Esto lo que provoca es que puedas acceder a todo el contenido del modulo sin tener que escribir cada vez numpy pudiendo escribir solo np. Por ejemplo si quisieses acceder a `numpy.linspace()` en tu caso después de definir el alias np podrías hacerlo simplement poniendo `np.linspace()`

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero esto no es una respuesta. Si necesitas realizar un comentario sobre otra respuesta debes tener suficiente reputación para hacerlo, y para ganar reputación puedes realizar buenas preguntas y/o buenas respuestas. Lo siento, mientras no lo tengas no puedes realizar algunos comentarios como este y no debes usar las respuestas para ello.

Comment: Además de lo que dijo Masterguru, decir "la respuesta que dio el usuario de arriba" no siempre señalará a la respuesta que esperas. Las respuestas están ordenadas por cantidad de votos positivos u otro orden elegido por el que ve tu respuesta. Por ejemplo si tu respuesta tuviera más votos positivos que la "del usuario de arriba", tu respuesta aparecerá por encima de la de dicho usuario. Si quieres referirte a una respuesta en especifico, puedes obtener un link que dirige a dicha respuesta con el botón "compartir" abajo a la izquierda de la respuesta.